# Permuting Letters Of A Word - Clarification needed

Tags: java, permutation

I was searching for a method to permute a word in java and came across this code.I'm actually learning it myself and facing some difficulty in understanding certain portions of the code :

1. Firstly what type of variable is this:  `used = new boolean[ in .length()]`  ?
   I've never seen such a boolean variable declaration.
2. What is the basic logic behind the functioning of this snippet?

   for (int i = 0; i < in .length(); ++i) {
             if (used[i]) {
               continue;
             }
             out.append( in .charAt(i));
             used[i] = true;
             permute();
             used[i] = false;
             out.setLength(out.length() - 1);

**THE ORIGINAL PROGRAM WAS**

```
public class Permutations {
  boolean[] used;
  StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
  String in ;
  public Permutations(String str) { in = str;
    used = new boolean[ in .length()];
  }
  public void permute() {
    if (out.length() == in .length()) {
      System.out.println(out);
      return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < in .length(); ++i) {
      if (used[i]) {
        continue;
      }
      out.append( in .charAt(i));
      used[i] = true;
      permute();
      used[i] = false;
      out.setLength(out.length() - 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: one question per question

Comment: At most half of this question is a duplicate of the cited question, and even then, that part is about a *declaration*, not an *initialization*.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson i don't think so.

Comment: what part of *one question per question* is not clear, and the the duplicate explains what that syntax is pretty clearly, if it does not make sense then you probably need more information that would be **too broad** as well. As for the *rest of the question*, that should be another question, and it would be a pretty poor one at that. If you disagree **edit** the question and **improve it so it is conformant** and see what happens.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: The cited "duplicate" does not say anything about specifying the size of the array, syntax or semantics; its does spell out how to initialize an array, which this question is not about.  Try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is an array of booleans.
2. Once you find an unused character (`used[i]` is false), append it to `out`, flag it as used (`used[i]=true`) & `permute()` what is left.  Once that is done, mark it as unused (`used[i]=false`) & remove the character you appended to `out` (`out.setLength(out.length()-1)`), so your loop can continue looking for unused characters.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: You first: elaborate on what you don't understand.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: I answered that (see item 2); what problem(s) do you have with the answer?

Comment: It would be useful if you can show me a dry run...

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: Because you can't run it yourself?

Comment: see i know i'm being irritating but this part ...used[i] = false;
      out.setLength(out.length() - 1);...i'm still having a problem when tried to dry run with {a,b,c}

Comment: Hey thanks...i finally got it :-)